# Paste multiple lines individually in each line in visual block mode

Tags: c#, excel, vim

I have an excel sheet with multple key value pairs, like so:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 89 |
| 99 | 87 |
| 98 | 86 |
| ... | ... |

And so on. I want to paste this data into a C# list, like so:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<double, double>> MyList
    = new List<KeyValuePair<double, double>> { 
            new KeyValuePair<double, double>(100, 89), 
            new KeyValuePair<double, double>(99, 87), 
            new KeyValuePair<double, double>(98, 86), 
            [...]
```

I tried highlighting the space in the `new KeyValuePair(|)`, going into visual block mode with `C-v`and pasting with `p` or even `i, C-v`, but that inserts all copied/yanked lines from the clipboard/register after each cursor and not one by one in each line, a bit like so:

```
            new KeyValuePair<double, double>(100, 89
                                             99, 87
                                             98, 86
                                             [...]
            ),
            new KeyValuePair<double, double>(100, 89
                                             99, 87
                                             98, 86
                                             [...]
            ),
```

Instead of what I want, which is what you can see above.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Visual-block mode doesn't seem to be right tool for the job, if only because the text you are trying to put was not yanked in visual-block mode.

Instead, you could just put the copied text *as-is*:

```
100 89
99  87
98  86
```

and transform that into the desired construct with a bunch of substitutions:

```
:'[,']s/^/new KeyValuePair<double, double>(/
:'[,']s/\t/, /
:'[,']s/$/),/
```

or a single one if you like challenges (and capture groups).

Answer (score 1):

you need to use multiple select lines to copy/cut data ***before paste***

[image: demo multiple paste]

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex substitution.

Regex : `((\d+) (\d+))`
Substitution : `new KeyValuePair<double, double>($2, $3),`

https://regex101.com/r/B83YAx/1/